# Sagemaker AutoML not finding .gzip file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-sagemaker

I have a file saved in an s3 bucket with the extension `.gzip`. I am then launching an AutoML job using boto3, but it does not find the file (I am certain it is in there). I get this error in the log of my sagemaker processing job:

```
Caused by: [Errno 2] FIFO 0 of the SageMaker pipe channel cannot be opened.: No such file or directory
```

Here is the code:

```
# https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker/client/create_auto_ml_job_v2.html
dict_response = cls_client.create_auto_ml_job_v2(
    AutoMLJobName=str_job_name,
    AutoMLJobInputDataConfig=[
        {
            'ChannelType': 'training',
            'ContentType': 'x-application/vnd.amazon+parquet',
            'CompressionType': 'Gzip',
            'DataSource': {
                'S3DataSource': {
                    'S3DataType': 'S3Prefix',
                    'S3Uri': f's3://{str_project}/03_models/aaron/00_preprocessing/02_make_dfs/{str_df_name}'
                }
            }
        },
    ],
    OutputDataConfig={
        'KmsKeyId': str_kms_id,
        'S3OutputPath': f's3://{str_project}/03_models/{str_job_name}'
    },
    AutoMLProblemTypeConfig={
        'TabularJobConfig': {
            'CandidateGenerationConfig': {
                'AlgorithmsConfig': [
                    {
                        'AutoMLAlgorithms': [ # empty means it uses all of them
                        ]
                    },
                ]
            },
            'Mode': 'ENSEMBLING', # ensembling uses autogluon
            'ProblemType': 'BinaryClassification',
            'TargetAttributeName': 'target', # target name
        }
    },
    RoleArn=str_role,
    AutoMLJobObjective={
        'MetricName': 'F1'
    },
    ModelDeployConfig={
        'AutoGenerateEndpointName': False,
        'EndpointName': f'{str_job_name}-endpoint'
    }
)
pprint(dict_response)
```

It works fine when I use `.csv` (with content type as `text/csv;header=present` and compression type as `None`), but I cannot get it to work with a file with `.gzip` extension. How do I fix this?